# Backbone Boilerplate - dynamic routes - How to pass id into view?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm working with Backbone.js using [Backbone Boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate) and what I'm looking for is a way to pass an id of a dynamic route into the view. So the view can download stuff (via xhr) depends on the string in that id.

Static route usually looks like this:

```
router.on('route:some-route', function () {
  require(['views/some-view'], function (ViewPage) {
    var viewPage = Vm.create(appView, 'viewPage', ViewPage);
    viewPage.render();
  });
});
```

For dynamic one you simply need to include the route parameter as an argument:

```
router.on('route:some-route', function (id) {
  ......
});
```

So I need a solution where the route parameter can be passed into the view. What is the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: What's `Vm.create`? Normally when you create view with `new View()`, you could pass it as an option, like `new View({thingId:id})`.

Comment: Vm is View Manager, https://github.com/thomasdao/Backbone-View-Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out. It's simple. You just need to pass the id to view render.

```
viewPage.render(id);
```

Comment: I was wondering, how do you do something with the id? I am trying to load a view with different content based on the id, so I want to be able to say to load content at position[id] in the array... any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my backbone boilerplate https://github.com/hbarroso/backbone-boilerplate

I think this exactly what you need with dynamic routing

Comment: Using your boilerplate, how does one pass parameters to modules. I have a module that is routed as follows:

    `router.route("v2/site/:id", "main", function () {
        console.log("Site route trigger");
        this.loadModule("bundles/project/main");
    });`

How do I reference that "id" parameter from within main.js?